# What is the Godox SHOOT setting for?

Tags: wireless-flash, remote, smartphone, godox

I was going through my Godox transmitter settings, and there's this cryptic one called SHOOT:

[image: screengrab on XPro of settings]

What do those three settings mean? And when would I want to use them? The Godox user manual isn't very clear on this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use these settings to control how and when the transmitters send settings changes out to the lights.  More specifically, when you have multiple shooters sharing the same lights, or if you want to remotely adjust your strobe settings and use a remote shutter.

The settings are:

- [image: One-head icon] **Single shooter mode**: To save on battery power, settings for the lights are only pushed out after you change a setting on the transmitter.
- [image: three-head icon] **Multiple shooter mode**: To avoid having the wrong settings on the lights between shared shooters, settings are pushed out to the lights for every shot, regardless of whether they've been changed on the transmitter.
- [image: APP] **Application mode**. To allow a second transmitter to control the power/group settings, this mode sets the on-camera transmitter to send only the sync (fire) command and never send settings. Useful if you are use a remote shutter release or external light meter, so you can fire and adjust power on the lights remotely from the camera.

  It's called "APP" because it was first designed to work in conjunction with the A1 smartphone trigger and GodoxPhoto app for smart device remote control of the lights. The A1 can act as an in-hand remote, but cannot be used on a hotshoe. However, APP mode does *not* require that you use the app.

  Confusingly, if the app communicates directly over bluetooth with the *on-camera* transmitter (e.g., X2T, Flashpoint R2 Pro II), then APP mode should **not** be set, because it's the on-camera transmitter that communicates the power setting changes from the app to the lights.

### X1T equivalent custom functions

On the X1T, this functionality was not included on initial release, and was added in firmware updates as two additional custom functions:

- Non-Fuji versions: **C.Fn-08** is **multi-shooter** mode and **C.Fn-09** is **APP** mode.
- X1T-F: **C.Fn-09** is **multi-shooter** mode and **C.Fn-10** is **APP** mode.

Having both turned off puts you in single-shooter mode.  I have no clue what happens if you turn them both on. :D